# AngularJS can we trigger the move animation event manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

In the ng-repeat section there are animations event handler for enter, leave and move. But the move event is only triggered when we resort or filter the array used for ng-repeat. What if I only change the attribute values of my objects. Then no event is triggered at all. Is there a way to trigger the event manually after I have changed the object attribute?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15002/

Html:

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="d in data">
          <div class="lala" style="width: {{d.a}}px">foo</div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{a:100},  {a:120}];

    // I would like to animate the value changes
    $scope.change = function()  {
        $scope.data[0].a = 110;
        $scope.data[1].a = 90;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your class definitions are wrong.

```
.lala,
.lala.ng-enter,
.lala.ng-move,
.lala.ng-leave {
     background-color: grey;
     -webkit-transition:all 1s linear;
     -moz-transition:1s linear all;
     -o-transition:1s linear all;
     transition:all 1s linear;
 }
```

See the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6x4v8b3q/).

Answer (score 0):

just add transition to the main class

```
.lala{
   transition:0.5s;
   background-color:grey;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15006/